# Bash:How to display regular files that have been changed at least x minutes ago, but not earlier that y minutes ago?

Tags: bash

I want to write a script that will find and display regular files from given directory that have been changed at last 1 minutes ago, but not earlier that 10 minutes ago.

What i done dont work.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(find $1 -type f -mmin +1 -mmin -10)
do
echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Could you please explain "dont work"?

Comment: Why `$1`? Do you provide the path as argument to the script?

Comment: Yes, i do. Yes, i do.

Comment: @user233352 The for loop is redundant and might actually cause errors if there are spacing issues. Don't understand why not just `find "$1" -type f -mmin +1 -mmin -10`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not explaining how it "doesn't work" but what you have will break if you pass in arguments with spaces in them.

```
find "$1" -type f -mmin +1 -mmin -10
```

This should work for one argument with spaces or other problematic characters in it.

```
find "$@" -type f -mmin +1 -mmin -10
```

This allows you to pass in multiple paths on the command line, with proper quoting.

Try `mkdir "foo bar" "ick poo"` and run the script on those.

```
./myscript foo bar ick poo   # won't work
```

This obviously receives four string arguments, not two directory names with spaces in them.  Not good.

```
./myscript "foo bar" "ick poo"
```

This works *provided* your script properly quotes the command-line arguments internally.  An unquoted `$1` turns into two arguments `foo` and `bar` whereas a properly quoted `"$1"` correctly refers to the directory named `foo bar`.

There is a wealth of guides to shell quoting but they are not getting the attention they deserve.  Many introductory texts fail to explain these issues properly, or even contain examples with improper quoting.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to escape spaces when calling the script you can do

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="$@"
find "$dir" -type f -mmin +1 -mmin -10
```

e.g. output

```
$ ./script test dir
test dir/test.txt
```

Otherwise just do

```
#!/bin/bash
find "$1" -type f -mmin +1 -mmin -10
```

e.g. output

```
$ ./script "test dir"
test dir/test.txt
```

Also make sure you permissions are locked down to only be executable for you, to prevent injection attacks.

Comment: What are you using `"$@"`? what will happen if you pass 2 arguments to the script?

Comment: @glenn jackman It will treat it as one argument. I am assuming the poster is getting some spacing error related to the input, so just provided 2 ways that could resolve it, though would obviously prefer more info on the "don't work".

Comment: You missed my point: if you do `./script dir1 dir2 dir3`, how will `find` behave when it's first argument is the single word `"dir1 dir2 dir3"`? Surely it will throw a "no such directory" error. You just want `find "$@" ...` or `find "$1" ...` I think. If you want to assign `"$@"` to a variable, you need to use an array: `dirs=("$@"); find "${dirs[@]}" ...`. Then `./script "dir with space" another_dir` will work correctly

Comment: @glenn jackman I just meant that it would work for `./script dir with space` without escaping or quoting out the spaces. Though agree that it really isn't the best practice overall since it goes against how arguments are generally treated in bash.